# Expected enum `std::result::Result`, found struct `std::vec::Vec`

Tags: vector, rust

I want to write a function that takes an integer, finds the divisors, and returns a vector with these values. I always get this error `` expected enum std::result::Result, found struct `std::vec::Vec` ``. Why does this happen? How do I prevent it now and in the future?

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", run(24));
}

pub fn run(integer: i32) -> Result<Vec<u32>, String> {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![];

    for i in 2..integer {
        if integer % i == 0 {
            v.push(i);
        }
    }
    v
}
```

Here's the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
5  | pub fn run(integer: i32) -> Result<Vec<u32>, String> {
   |                             ------------------------ expected `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u32>, std::string::String>` because of return type
...
13 |     v
   |     ^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u32>, std::string::String>`
            found struct `std::vec::Vec<i32>`
```

Comment: You have stated you are returning a `Result`. You then don't return a `Result`. Can you help us understand what the missing piece is?

Comment: how do i convert Vec to Result then?

Comment: I encourage you to read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) which describes these fundamental Rust concepts in deep detail.

Comment: ok be right back once i read it.

Comment: You won't be "right back" if you read that book the right way. It takes a few weeks to read.

Comment: sounds like you never wanted a `Result` in the first place. Just change the signature to `pub fn run(integer: i32) -> Vec<u32>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the return value you're providing at the end of the function has type `Vec<i32>`, whereas you've declared the function to return a value of type `Result<Vec<u32>, String>`, which is not the same. Rust's type system is quite strict and will not implicitly insert a conversion here. You can use the `Ok` constructor to convert your `Vec<i32>` into a `Result<Vec<i32>, String>`, like this:

```
pub fn run(integer: i32) -> Result<Vec<u32>, String> {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![];

    for i in 2..integer {
        if integer % i == 0 {
            v.push(i);
        }
    }
    Ok(v)
}
```

This will now give a different error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:8
   |
13 |     Ok(v)
   |        ^ expected `u32`, found `i32`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::vec::Vec<u32>`
              found struct `std::vec::Vec<i32>`
```

There is still a mismatch in the types because the declared return type involved `u32` whereas the provided value involved `i32`. Again, Rust will not implicitly convert between these types, so we would need to change one of the two types to make them agree.

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: Right, changing the declared return type would be another way to make it work, given that the `Err` variant is unused. I was assuming it might be used later, for instance, to handle inputs for which the list of divisors wouldn't make sense (for instance in case `integer` = 0, because here there would be infinitely many divisors).